# Is there a way to simulate the 2016 MacBook Pro's TouchBar in Xcode 8.1?

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm looking to write a program tailored to the announced, but not-yet-released MacBook Pro with Touch Bar. Is there a way to simulate the Touch Bar similar to the way iPhone/Apple Watch apps can be simulated from Xcode?

Comment: Found this after a 30-second Google search https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/66629

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are references and sample code [here](https://developer.apple.com/macos/touch-bar/) (and it works with Xcode 8.1).

> Download and install the latest versions of Xcode 8 and macOS Sierra, and use the development resources to learn about creating apps that use the Touch Bar.

Most notably,
[Showing the Touch Bar simulator in Xcode](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.1/#/dev7a8cb8a8c):

> Show the Touch Bar simulator by choosing **Window > Show Touch Bar**.
>
> The simulator represents the Touch Bar in a floating window regardless of whether your Mac is equipped with a Touch Bar. Use the simulator to preview, test, and debug the NSTouchBar objects you define in your app.

---

Edit: Touch Bar simulation isn't available on macOS 10.12.1 build 16B2555. If you're running this build you'll need to manually download and install 10.12 build 12B2657 (or later) via https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1897

Comment: Thanks. I think the reason I couldn't find it is because my build of 10.12.1 is too old, as per @EmilioPelaez' comment to my question.

Answer (score 2):

Command + Shift + 8 is the shortcut for same